# Node "Error: Cannot find module 'node:process'" when using global fastify-cli (mac)

Tags: node.js, npm, node-modules, fastify

I'm setting up a new mac dev machine, and have gotten node, npm, and nvm installed. All seems fine within a single project directory. However, when trying to install and use `fastify-cli`, I'm receiving an error:

```
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:892
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module 'node:process'
Require stack:
- /Users/a/.nvm/versions/node/v14.17.5/lib/node_modules/fastify-cli/node_modules/marked-terminal/index.cjs
- /Users/a/.nvm/versions/node/v14.17.5/lib/node_modules/fastify-cli/node_modules/blessed-contrib/lib/widget/markdown.js
- /Users/a/.nvm/versions/node/v14.17.5/lib/node_modules/fastify-cli/node_modules/blessed-contrib/index.js
- /Users/a/.nvm/versions/node/v14.17.5/lib/node_modules/fastify-cli/docs.js
- /Users/a/.nvm/versions/node/v14.17.5/lib/node_modules/fastify-cli/cli.js
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:889:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:745:27)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:961:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:92:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/a/.nvm/versions/node/v14.17.5/lib/node_modules/fastify-cli/node_modules/marked-terminal/index.cjs:3:17)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1072:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1101:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:937:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:778:12)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:961:19) {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: [
    '/Users/a/.nvm/versions/node/v14.17.5/lib/node_modules/fastify-cli/node_modules/marked-terminal/index.cjs',
    '/Users/a/.nvm/versions/node/v14.17.5/lib/node_modules/fastify-cli/node_modules/blessed-contrib/lib/widget/markdown.js',
    '/Users/a/.nvm/versions/node/v14.17.5/lib/node_modules/fastify-cli/node_modules/blessed-contrib/index.js',
    '/Users/a/.nvm/versions/node/v14.17.5/lib/node_modules/fastify-cli/docs.js',
    '/Users/a/.nvm/versions/node/v14.17.5/lib/node_modules/fastify-cli/cli.js'
  ]
}
```

Steps to reproduce:

1. `$ npm install --global fastify-cli` (succeeds)
2. `$ fastify generate myproject` (also produces above error)
3. `$ fastify` (also produces above error)

This likely doesn't have much to do with `fastify`. It seems to me that the global package is not finding Node for some reason, but I may be wrong.

- I'm using zshell
- I've got xcode installed
- I've upgraded the version of node i'm using
- I'm able to start a fastify app from the app directory directly/without using the generator

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I fixed the error following the answer in this [GitHub issue reply](https://github.com/fastify/fastify-cli/issues/467#issuecomment-1055172879)

> node internal syntax (e.g.: node:<core_module_name>) is not supported by Node.js 14.16.0

The CLI needs node version >= 14.18

Steps:

1. Upgrade node using nvm to 14.18.0 (the last lts in 14.x).
2. Set default version 14.18.0 or above.

Answer (score -1):

you need to run
`npm i @types/node`

Answer (score -3):

I solved it by switching the current user to a root user.

If you are using a Mac, try to switch to a root user account and do the same thing again.

I assigned my previous account as 'administrator' under system preferences, but this won't solve the issue. The problem was perfectly solved when I switched to my primary account.

Hope this could help!